# Bad array? Bad foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, json

Sorry for the huge ignorance on the topic, but I really have no idea where to look other than this website when I come into trouble with my PHP.

What I'm trying to do here is use pre-designated IDs to call particular movies from a database. But all I get is an 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()' message on the second and third foreach's below.

Here's my code in the head:

```
//Custom lists of movies to bring in
//New Releases list
 $films_new_releases = array(40805, 46705, 41630, 44564, 39451, 20352, 43933, 49009, 49797, 42194);
 //Most Popular list
 $films_most_popular = array(27205, 16290, 10138, 41733, 37799, 18785, 19995, 17654, 10140, 12162);

//Get information from address bar
$list = $_GET['l'];
if ($list == 'new releases') {
    $list_chosen = $films_new_releases;
}
elseif ($list == 'most popular') {
    $list_chosen = $films_most_popular;
}
else {
    $list_chosen = $films_new_releases;
}
```

And in amongst the body:

```
  // Loop through each film returned
  foreach ($list_chosen as $list_chosen_film) {

    $films_result = $tmdb->getMovie($list_chosen_film);
    $film = json_decode($films_result);

    // Set default poster image to use if film doesn't have one
    $backdrop_url = 'images/placeholder-film.gif';

    // Loop through each poster for current film
    foreach($film->backdrops as $backdrop) {
      if ($backdrop->image->size == 'poster') {
        $backdrop_url = $backdrop->image->url;
      }
    }

    echo '<div class="view-films-film">
        <a href="film.php?id=' . $film->id . '"><img src="' . $backdrop_url . '" alt="' . $film->name . '" /></a>
            <div class="view-films-film-snippet">
                <h2><a href="film.php?id=' . $film->id . '">' . $film->name . '</a></h2>';
    if ($film->certification != null) {
           echo '<img src="images/bbfc-' . strtolower($film->certification) . '.png" alt="" />';
    }
    echo '      <h3>Starring</h3>
                <p>';
    $num_actors = 0;
    foreach ($film->cast as $cast) {
    if ($cast->job == 'Actor') {
      echo '<a href="person.php?id=' . $cast->id . '">' . $cast->name . '</a> ';
      $num_actors++;
      if ($num_actors == 5)
        break;
    }
    echo '      </p>
                <h3>Director</h3>
                <p>';
    foreach ($film->cast as $cast) {
        if ($cast->job == 'Director') {
            echo '<a href="person.php?id=' . $cast->id . '">' . $cast->name . '</a> ';
        }
    }
    echo '      </p>
            </div>
        </div>';
  }
  // End films
  }
```

The little testing I've done is checking what `$list_chosen`, `$list_chosen_film`, `$films_result` and `$film` actually contain by printing them at the bottom of the page.

`$list_chosen` shows - `Array`, `$list_chosen_film` shows - `42194`, `$films_result` shows the entire JSON string, `$film` shows - `Array`.

Comment: what's the result of: var_dump($film) ?

Comment: Here's the start of the result of var_dump($film):
`array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#249 (33) { ["popularity"]=> int(3) ["translated"]=> bool(true)......`
I'd post the whole lot, but its far too big

Comment: Why isn't this post getting attention then, if posting an exact duplicate of it does? Which is then closed?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding:

```
print_r($film->backdrop);
```

before the second foreach() loop. Before the error message it won't be an array or it will contain zero elements (not allowed). If you also add:

```
echo $films_result;
```

you will be able to debug it and fully understand what is wrong. If not, post the whole output in your question.

Comment: I did the `print_r($film->backdrops);` and it printed nothing. I did the same for `$list_chosen`, `$list_chosen_film`, `$films_result`, `$film` and they all seem to work perfectly... Here I've saved the entire `$film` output -> http://freetexthost.com/4cfneqdqty. It looks fine to me?? Backdrop's in there and everyone

Answer (score 1):

This happens, because - as error displayed by PHP informed you - you have provided wrong parameter to `foreach` loop, probably `null` or some other value. Make sure you are providing array to foreach.

Also, every time you use `foreach`, do it like that:

```
if (count($some_list) > 0) {
    foreach ($some_list as $list_item) {
        // code for each item on the list
    }
} else {
    // code when there is nothing on the list
}
```

This will ensure you will not see errors just because there is nothing on the list.

**EDIT:**

On the [documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) you can find some tip how to avoid such errors if the collection you are trying to iterate through is empty. Just cast the collection to `array` type:

```
foreach ((array) $some_list as $list_item) {
    // code for each item on the list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a dump of $film? The error is telling you that you are pointing to an object that cannot be iterated through (most likely null).

Comment: Here's the start of the result of var_dump($film):
`array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#249 (33) { ["popularity"]=> int(3) ["translated"]=> bool(true)......`
I'd post the whole lot, but its far too big